# The audio from one window refuses to play through my headphones, but will play through the monitor

Tags: windows-10, audio

So, i was doing something in another tab with the audio working just fine, but when i started up minecraft to play with a friend, i was greeted by the music playing loudly through the monitor. I thought i could solve this by disabling that output, because the output was being split, but the only thing that happened was there not being any output for the audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set per-application output devices & volumes from the sound control panel.

Settings > System > Sound > App volume & device prefs
Make sure the correct device is selected.

[image]